# 150 sites from dedicated server to azure (advice please)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We have dedicated servers with UK hosting providers (UkServers, Rackspace & Fasthosts) for a lot of websites.

We develop software on Azure using WebApps and it's perfect for what we use it for.

Now though, we'd like to get rid of our dedicated servers for about 150 sites and move everything to the cloud.  All of these sites are .net framework or .net core with SQL server (but sql can easily move to azure without too much fuss), there's lots of console apps that run along side and scheduled tasks, lets encrypt renewals etc.

In the past we've migrated sites from traditional hosting to web apps, but doing a ton of work along the way (moving to blob storage instead of local etc).

Our typical server spec will be:
20 core / 40 thread intel Xeons (two CPUs).
128 GB Ram
1TB SSD Raided boot drive (we tend to use this for database storage as well)
4TB HHD Raided storage drive (where most sites sit, plus all their media)

These cost us about £500 (about $650) per month outside of Rackspace and we will generally have unlimited 1gps bandwidth.

We'll generally put about 25 sites on each server (normally CMS sites) and we manage all the sites via iis over VPN RDP.

The servers are overkill and most of the sites aren't seeing huge amounts of traffic (some do, but we're happy to migrate them to webapps and do the job properly using all the tools and APIs that azure offers).

For the majority though, these sites just sit there and don't use a ton of resource and we want to see if we can move them all to azure servers somehow.

**The main question would be:**

If you have a windows server with IIS running 25 sites and you want a quick way to move them to azure what are our options?

We do a lot with Azure WebApps, but nothing with proper VMs so I just want to know what we should be looking at.

I'm presuming there's a lot of dev companies in my situation with tons of legacy sites to support and I just want rid of our servers (one of our hosts just had a 4 hour outage across an entire data hall and it just feels really silly to still be hosting everything this way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it all depends how those legacy websites were written but I assume the less effort would be to move them into App Service plans. One App plan can host multiple apps pretty much said unlimited apps but it depends on a load, and depends on tier you can scale to 10 servers in [Standard plan](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/pricing/details/app-service/plans/), 20 in Premium which is also good since if you need to get more azure can auto scale so you pay for what you use.

For databases you have way better options with [Azure Sql Pool](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/sql-database/elastic/). Specially that some websites dont have much load it will share resources  between your databases.

The only thing I see could be more effort is your background jobs. The easiest way would be to spin VM and put them there, the better way is to move them into Azure Functions.

If you apps are not cloud ready, I mean using in memory session, using disc and so on and you dont want to rewrite it then instead of App service you will need to use VM and the only scale option would be to add more resources to VM.

And lastly people tend to believe that clouds are magic and dont have outages its just wrong :) To avoid outages you need to design for that and some times you need to go multi region and even multi cloud